# check if checkbox is checked using jQuery then add a class to the closest td

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

i'm using ASP.NET ,i have a gridview with a checkbox element , i want to check if checkbox is checked add a class to the clossest td that can change the background-color to black

i use this but it does not work :

Js ((Purpose of Tasting)) :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(":CheckBox").closest('td').addClass("OnSelectTr");
});
```

CSS :

```
.OnSelectTr
{
    background-color:Black;
}
```

ASP.NET CODE :

```
<asp:GridView ID="DossierGV" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                            AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="DossierPF" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            DataKeyNames="ID_Dossier">
                          <Columns>
                              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choisir">
                                  <EditItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                                  </EditItemTemplate>
                                  <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                                  </ItemTemplate>
                              </asp:TemplateField>
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_Dossier" HeaderText="ID_Dossier" ReadOnly="True" 
                                  SortExpression="ID_Dossier" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_Entreprise" HeaderText="ID_Entreprise" 
                                  SortExpression="ID_Entreprise" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Depot" HeaderText="Date_Depot" 
                                  SortExpression="Date_Depot" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_Etude" HeaderText="Type_Etude" 
                                  SortExpression="Type_Etude" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Dernier_Type" HeaderText="Dernier_Type" 
                                  SortExpression="Dernier_Type" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Eligibile" HeaderText="Eligibile" 
                                  SortExpression="Eligibile" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Fiche_Information" HeaderText="Fiche_Information" 
                                  SortExpression="Fiche_Information" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Buletin_Adhesion" HeaderText="Buletin_Adhesion" 
                                  SortExpression="Buletin_Adhesion" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Fiche_Renseignment" HeaderText="Fiche_Renseignment" 
                                  SortExpression="Fiche_Renseignment" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Attestation" HeaderText="Attestation" 
                                  SortExpression="Attestation" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_Cabinet" HeaderText="ID_Cabinet" 
                                  SortExpression="ID_Cabinet" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Montant_Demander" HeaderText="Montant_Demander" 
                                  SortExpression="Montant_Demander" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Duree" HeaderText="Duree" SortExpression="Duree" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Porcentage_Taux" HeaderText="Porcentage_Taux" 
                                  SortExpression="Porcentage_Taux" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="Nom_Giac" HeaderText="Nom_Giac" 
                                  SortExpression="Nom_Giac" />
                          </Columns>
                      </asp:GridView>
```

code source in the navigator :

```
<div class="GridViewDiv">

              <div id="Corps_DossierUpdatePanel">
                      <div>

        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Corps_DossierGV" style="border-collapse:collapse;">

            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Choisir</th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$ID_Dossier&#39;)">ID_Dossier</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$ID_Entreprise&#39;)">ID_Entreprise</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Date_Depot&#39;)">Date_Depot</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Type_Etude&#39;)">Type_Etude</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Dernier_Type&#39;)">Dernier_Type</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Eligibile&#39;)">Eligibile</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Fiche_Information&#39;)">Fiche_Information</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Buletin_Adhesion&#39;)">Buletin_Adhesion</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Fiche_Renseignment&#39;)">Fiche_Renseignment</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Attestation&#39;)">Attestation</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$ID_Cabinet&#39;)">ID_Cabinet</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Montant_Demander&#39;)">Montant_Demander</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Duree&#39;)">Duree</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Porcentage_Taux&#39;)">Porcentage_Taux</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$Corps$DossierGV&#39;,&#39;Sort$Nom_Giac&#39;)">Nom_Giac</a></th>

            </tr><tr>

                <td>

                                      <input id="Corps_DossierGV_CheckBox1_0" type="checkbox" name="_ctl0:Corps:DossierGV:_ctl2:CheckBox1" />

                                  </td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>10/12/2011 00:00:00</td><td>DS</td><td>IN</td><td>oui</td><td>oui</td><td>oui</td><td>oui</td><td>oui</td><td>1</td><td>1000,00</td><td>10</td><td>70</td><td>GIAC1-IMME</td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>



</div>
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to read that source but, do you actually have only one checkbox? Is it the way it's supposed to be? Also, do you want to apply the css to only the next cell or the entire row?

Comment: Your checkbox selector is wrong. Try `$("input[type='checkbox']").closest('td').addClass("OnSelectTr");`

Comment: @Fabrício Matté 
i want to apply the css in the entire row , and yes in my page i only have checkboxes in a grid view

Comment: @mattytommo [$(':checkbox')](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) is a shorthand for `$("[type='checkbox']")`, but you're right, it's supposed to be lowercase.

Comment: @mattytommo i did try your methode but i steel face the same problem.. nothings happend

Comment: i try this one too but steel have the same problem :s :s 
$(':checkbox').change(function () { $(this).closest('td').addClass("OnSelectTr");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've specified that the class should be added to the entire row, you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':checkbox').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).attr('checked'))
            $(this).parents('tr').addClass('OnSelectTr');
        else
            $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('OnSelectTr');
    });
});​
```

***[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J65ap/)***

It will bind the function to be called whenever a checkbox's value is changed, adding or removing its parent tr's class according to the checked value.

Note that `.on` is only supported in JQuery 1.7+, for older versions replace `.on` by `.live`.

Comment: tnkks @Fabrício Matté fr your help but unfortunately .. steel got the same probleme :'(

Comment: What's the "problem" specifically? The class isn't being added? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no error occurred in mozilla firefox console
in line 198 .. th place i have the checkbox element

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using in your page? You can try replacing `.on` by `.live` if it is JQuery < 1.7. If that doesn't work then something else could be breaking your code, as for your isolated generated HTML, my function will work regardless of when the checkboxes are generated (you can even add more of them on the fly). Make sure the JQuery lib is included correctly, if there are no errors I can't see how this wouldn't work. Maybe start stripping (commenting) your code to the minimum and check if it works.

Comment: yes yes dudde  this is when i turn .live to .on and change the version of j-query from 1.4 to 1.7 the probleme is solved tnksssssssssssssssssssssssssssss dudde ^^

Comment: No problem ^^ Click the "V" mark at the top-left side of my answer to mark my answer as accepted if that's all. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are invoking that JS, but I have a feeling the selector is not quite right. I would add it as an onchange event on the checkbox and then change the selector to this:

```
$(this).closest('td').addClass("OnSelectTr");
```

You also might want to change addClass to toggleClass as this will handle unchecking as well.

EDIT ok try this for initalizing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("checkbox").change(function () { $(this).closest('td').addClass("OnSelectTr"); });
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

    $(":CheckBox").closest('td').addClass("OnSelectTr");

});

Comment: Ah, what you are doing is on page load adding the class to all checkboxes. Probably not the behavior you want, I edited my answer to correctly bind to the change event of the checkboxes.

Comment: i did try your methode but i steel face the same problem :'( tnks Parco